# flutter video dimensions when showed does not match the real dimensions of the video

Tags: flutter, video, video-player

I am making a little flutter app.

I have  video with the following dimensions : 853 x 480 (16/9 aspect ratio). I use Chewie and import it via network.

When I play the video in landscape, my device is 896 pixels of width and I was expecting my video to make 853 pixels of width.

I was wrong.

Actually, when manually adapting the width of the parent container (colored in blue to have a clear view) I realized that the width of my video was only about 735 pixels wide.

I made some searches and believed I had found the solution with MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio
but not...
I am using a IPhone 11 simulator and the device Pixel ratio when printed is 2.0 what doesn't correspond with the ratio 853/735.

Do you have an idea of the explanation and how to retrieve the actual ratio of 853/735 (that is normally unknown and probably varies between devices)?

Thanks a lot !

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a bug in Chewie because when I use the video player controller instead of the Chewie one with the same code I have no problem.